# How to allow only NTP using iptables?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall, router, ntp

I'm looking for a way to restrict internet traffic to one of the device on my network so that it can only access NTP an nothing else.
Now the easy solution would be to just allow destination port 123 for that device, but I have a problem with that.
If I do that, isn't it possible that the device connects to a (non-NTP) server on port 123 and leaks private information?

**Some more background:**

I have an IoT device which I can connect to from within my local network, but it also has the feature to send data to its cloud. With no clear way to turn that off, I'd like to make sure that the data doesn't leave my local network.

At first I simply blocked internet traffic for its ip in my router (Asuswrt firmware), but in case of a restart (e.g. power outage) its time resets to an old date. Then it tries to access an NTP server to get the correct time.

I checked the ips it tries to connect to and whitelisted one using iptables on the router. The time updated successfully, but on the next restart the ips have changed. I suspect this is because the NTP server on the router is set to `pool.ntp.org` so the actual server list changes over time.

So I'd like to make sure that the device can only communicate with a valid, known time server, without leaving the possibility for it to connect to some random host on port 123 and send non-time related data.

Is there a way to achieve that? Maybe the packets can be inspected to ensure it only contains data related to NTP?

Alternatively I'm also open to set up a local NTP server if that solves the problem, but that would be the scope of a separate question.

Comment: Hi Gabor, it's been a long time :)

Comment: Run your own NTP server, if you want to enter certain IP address. Or permit whole NTP and whole DNS and then you may use pool.ntp.org. There are solutions which would filter at the protocol level, but trust me, you don't want these.

Comment: Home networking questions should be asked on our sister site [su].

Comment: You could just set a static NTP server(s) instead of using pool.ntp.org. Your ISP probably has an NTP server you can use, you could go with NIST, or whatever.  Search Google for public NTP servers.

Comment: I was not aware of NIST, I picked one from that and will use it until I set up my local NTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `iptables` `string` match module to match the packet contents so that it matches typical NTP protocol contents, and allow only those packets that match this criteria in your rules.

However, this is not 100% waterproof, you need to carefully assign the matching strings. Also, a malicious intruder could detect this and add the string to his own payload. That would be extremely unlikely.

Another option is to use an Intrusion Prevention System like Suricata, which does actual protocol analysis. However, I'm not sure if Suricata has direct capability to analyse NTP traffic.

Comment: If an attacker knows you are using the strings module that alone might be used for denial-of-service purposes, as the packet content matching is relatively expensive.

Comment: Ok this was what I was looking for. So it indeed is possible. Considering the downsides, however, I will likely go with a hand-picked time server from a different list first, then move on to set up my local NTP server. +1 for mentioning Suricata, I will look into it whether it can help in general to monitor trafic on my network

Answer (score 1):

So goal is allow NTP, and not allow exfiltration.

My solution would be to redirect all UDP 123 traffic to a known NTP server, maybe even internal. That way any NTP requests would only have NTP data or failures.

If exfiltration is the main concern, remember that DNS queries also is a possible risk.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning DNS exfiltration I was not aware of that and I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

[NTP has been previously been used to find port scan targets](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/02/using-ipv6-with-linux-youve-likely-been-visited-by-shodan-and-other-scanners/) in the too big to brute force IPv6 address space. Happens every day on the internet, but may be something you are not comfortable with.

Find out how the device locates an NTP server, watch its DNS and NTP traffic. Ideally it can be configured, possibly via [DHCPv6 option 56 NTP server](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml). Unfortunately, it may not be configurable.

Any default NTP Pool config must use a [vendor zone](https://www.pool.ntp.org/vendors.html) so use can be managed. If not, or worse if it uses a [specific volunteer service without asking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTP_server_misuse_and_abuse), please complain to the vendor.

Firewall outgoing traffic for this security zone as desired. Allow outgoing destination port 123/udp and incoming replies, deny everything else. I am not aware of widespread exfiltration or other bad data via the NTP port. Packet volumes should be low, one packet per few minutes per device, if you wished to capture and analyze or rate limit.

NTP does better with a diversity of sources. IP addresses and host names will change, rotating often when using the pool. Consider not filtering on NTP server destination address.

Yes, you can run your own NTP service. More useful if every device on the network can be configured to use it.